# Free, portable, all included, all in one, php Apache based server?

Tags: php, windows, apache, portability

Free, portable, all included, all in one, (opensource is + ) php server? I have a USB FLASH 16gb card. I want to install on to it some kind of PHP server - some programm.exe which i could run on different computers without installing - call some localhost/phpserver and get my php scripts running.
So where to go to get such thing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

XAMPP and instructions:

http://www.pendriveapps.com/xampp-portable-web-server/

Answer (score 0):

I'd try [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/); hopefully it has what you are looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest XAMPP also but instead of pendriveapp fork, you can use the original "xampp lite" package served from their offical site. I's pretty portable and you can use without setup.

By the way, your problem will not be the choosing package. Problem is, you'll need an extremly fast flash drive or card.